# Codeigniter generate increment ID for looping

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to import excel as json data in Codeigniter with generate id.

**my model**

```
    public function generateImpId() {
        $now = date('ymd');
        $check = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM OP_IMP_15 WHERE DATE(OP_IMP_15.created_at) = DATE(NOW())";
        $querycheck = $this->db->query($check);
        $id = $querycheck->row()->count;

        return 'IMPDEMO'.$now.str_pad($id, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
```

**my controller**

```
    //count row
    $lastRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheetnumber)->getHighestRow();       
    $countrow = $lastRow - 1;

    //start loop excel from 2nd row. Row 1 is title row
    for ($j=2; $j < $lastRow; $j++ ){
      $myArray[] = array(
        'site_id' => $objWorksheet->getCell('C'.$j)->getValue(),
        'site_name' => $objWorksheet->getCell('D'.$j)->getValue(),
        'id_site_doc'=> $objWorksheet->getCell('J'.$j)->getValue(),
        'id_project_doc' => $objWorksheet->getCell('K'.$j)->getValue(),
         //generate ID from model
        'implementation_id' => $this->M_MRCR_A->generateImpId(),
        ...
```

**the result**

```
{      "site_id":"AR001",
      "site_name":"Site AR 001",
      "id_site_doc":"5df1b4223269f818adab55af",
      "id_project_doc":"5da43895e619143bcff53ab1",
      "implementation_id":"IMPDEMO2003310001",
      "status":"implementation_created",
      "endstate":false,
      "created_by":"sgph_pm@mittapp.com",
      "counter_mr":"0",
      "tech_boq_ids":[


],
...
{      "site_id":"AR002",
      "site_name":"Site AR 002",
      "id_site_doc":"5df1b4223269f818adab55af",
      "id_project_doc":"5da43895e619143bcff53ab2",
      "implementation_id":"IMPDEMO2003310001",
      "status":"implementation_created",
      "endstate":false,
      "created_by":"sgph_pm@mittapp.com",
      "counter_mr":"0",
      "tech_boq_ids":[


],
```

**my expectation**

to make "implementation_id" increment based on how many rows the data will be imported and **format based on custom ID i'd made** (i can't use uuid). ex:
i have 3 row to be imported, so the value of $implementation_id will be : IMPDEMO2003310001, IMPDEMO2003310002, IMPDEMO2003310003

Comment: do you want to keep the `implementation_id` value or do you want to replace it with `$countrow`? what do you expect the `implementation_id` to have?

Comment: Maybe generating an uuid suits better?

Comment: @HastaDhana i've edited the question, i hope thats answer your question

Comment: @CarlosGant i cant, i should use custom ID because the requirement is different

Comment: And what's the **exact** problem with all that code? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since you already have the generated `implementation_id` value, and I have no idea what the `generateImpId()` function do, you could manually replace each generated `implementation_id` with the `$j` you have :

```php
//count row
$lastRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheetnumber)->getHighestRow();       
$countrow = $lastRow - 1;

//start loop excel from 2nd row. Row 1 is title row
for ($j=2; $j < $lastRow; $j++ ){
    $implementation_id = $this->M_MRCR_A->generateImpId();
    $implementation_id = substr($implementation_id, 0, -4) . str_pad($j-1, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // since $j starts with 2
    $myArray[] = array(
    'site_id' => $objWorksheet->getCell('C'.$j)->getValue(),
    'site_name' => $objWorksheet->getCell('D'.$j)->getValue(),
    'id_site_doc'=> $objWorksheet->getCell('J'.$j)->getValue(),
    'id_project_doc' => $objWorksheet->getCell('K'.$j)->getValue(),
        //generate ID from model
    'implementation_id' => $implementation_id,
    ...
```

Comment: Isn't this a long way round compared to using ++?

Comment: @NigelRen I guess `++` won't work since the id is a custom character and not an integer

Comment: Have you tried it -  `$implementationID = "IMPDEMO2003310001"; echo $implementationID++.PHP_EOL; echo $implementationID++.PHP_EOL; echo $implementationID++.PHP_EOL;`?

Answer (score 0):

You shoulnd't try to do everything in one single loop.

Maybe you should use a first iteration (for loop) to create the array, and then, a second iteration to fill this implementation_id field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting the start implementation ID at the start of the loop and just increment it each time (PHP can cope with incrementing a string like this)...

```
$implementationID = $this->M_MRCR_A->generateImpId();
//start loop excel from 2nd row. Row 1 is title row
for ($j=2; $j < $lastRow; $j++ ){
  $myArray[] = array(

     // ...

     //generate ID from model
    'implementation_id' => $implementationID++,
```

that should give you values like...

```
IMPDEMO2003310001
IMPDEMO2003310002
IMPDEMO2003310003
```